# How can I close pygames without closing tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame, sys

So I am trying to use Tkinter to receive a text input, and then run pygames from that to do an animation. I get an error though when I close Pygames.

A simplified version of how I plan to use Pygames:

```
def the_program():
    if spot.get().strip() == "":
        tkMessageBox.showerror("X", "Y")
    else:
        code = spot.get().strip()
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption('X')
        windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 0, 32)
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            pygame.display.update()
```

Running Tkinter:

```
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
text = Label(frame, text='X')
spot = Entry(frame)
button = Button(frame, text = 'Ready?', command = the_program) "Starts Pygames"
frame.pack()
text.pack()
spot.pack()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Pygames opens up fine and runs well, but when I close it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\Practice\legit Battle Master.py", line 82, in <module>
    root.mainloop()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1017, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1412, in __call__
    raise SystemExit, msg
```

How can I avoid this? I tried removing "sys.exit()", but python crashes.

Comment: select all your source code lines and press CTRL+K to create a better syntax highlighting and code formatting, please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to exit from the pygame mainloop with `sys.exit()`, which exits the whole running application, including the tkinter GUI you started before pygame. You should exit the pygame mainloop (the only `while` clause) with a conditional. e.g:

```
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            running = False
...
```

Comment: Same thing happened as when I removed sys.exit(). A crash window opens saying pythonw.exe has encounter a problem etc.

Comment: maybe you have to call pygame.quit() at the termination of your Tkinter program.

Comment: The crashes were from another problem in my program that I fixed. Thanks for the help it works now.

Comment: Well actually I added a an empty return after running = False